# How to inject EJB3 session bean into another session bean with JBoss 6

Tags: ejb-3.0, jboss6.x, myfaces

I'm trying to migrate a project that I didn't participate in from JBoss 4 to JBoss 6. The project consists of an EJB 3 backend and a MyFaces 1.1.4 frontend. I have included the MyFaces 1.1.4 libraries in the JBoss 6 jsf deployer.

I have a call from the frontend to a backend function through a helper class.

```
    PatientControllerEJB patientModule = BusinessHelper.getPatientServices();  
    patientModule.canCreatePatVisit( getUserContainer().getClientId(), patId, vType);
```

After that call I get a NullPointerException at the backend canCreatePatVisit function, in the session bean patientModule.

```
    @Stateless
    public class PatientControllerEJBBean extends ASBusinessLogicClass implements PatientControllerEJBLocal, PatientControllerEJBRemote {
        @Resource private SessionContext sessionCtx = null;

        @PersistenceContext(unitName="amedPU") EntityManager em;
        @EJB private AdminControllerEJBLocal admContr;
        @EJB private ConfigControllerEJBLocal confContr;

        ...

        public void canCreatePatVisit(int clientId, int patId, int visitTypeId) throws ValidationException {
            IVisitType vt = admContr.getVisitType(visitTypeId);
        ...
        }
    ...
    }
```

I debugged the project and I found out that em, admContr and confContr are all null. So I suppose there is a problem injecting a session bean in another session bean but I don't know what.

I have changed the web.xml version to 2.5 in the frontend and I am using the JBoss 6 libraries. Any help would be appreciated.

I'm including a portion of the stacktrace below in case it might be helpful.

```
Caused by: javax.ejb.EJBException: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.jboss.ejb3.tx2.impl.CMTTxInterceptor.handleExceptionInOurTx(CMTTxInterceptor.java:183)
    at org.jboss.ejb3.tx2.impl.CMTTxInterceptor.invokeInOurTx(CMTTxInterceptor.java:251)
    at org.jboss.ejb3.tx2.impl.CMTTxInterceptor.required(CMTTxInterceptor.java:349)
    at org.jboss.ejb3.tx2.impl.CMTTxInterceptor.invoke(CMTTxInterceptor.java:209)
    at org.jboss.ejb3.tx2.aop.CMTTxInterceptorWrapper.invoke(CMTTxInterceptorWrapper.java:52)
    at org.jboss.aop.joinpoint.MethodInvocation.invokeNext(MethodInvocation.java:102)
    at org.jboss.aspects.tx.TxPropagationInterceptor.invoke(TxPropagationInterceptor.java:76)
    at org.jboss.aop.joinpoint.MethodInvocation.invokeNext(MethodInvocation.java:102)
    at org.jboss.ejb3.tx.NullInterceptor.invoke(NullInterceptor.java:42)
    at org.jboss.aop.joinpoint.MethodInvocation.invokeNext(MethodInvocation.java:102)
    at org.jboss.ejb3.security.Ejb3AuthenticationInterceptorv2.invoke(Ejb3AuthenticationInterceptorv2.java:182)
    at org.jboss.aop.joinpoint.MethodInvocation.invokeNext(MethodInvocation.java:102)
    at org.jboss.ejb3.ENCPropagationInterceptor.invoke(ENCPropagationInterceptor.java:41)
    at org.jboss.aop.joinpoint.MethodInvocation.invokeNext(MethodInvocation.java:102)
    at org.jboss.ejb3.BlockContainerShutdownInterceptor.invoke(BlockContainerShutdownInterceptor.java:67)
    at org.jboss.aop.joinpoint.MethodInvocation.invokeNext(MethodInvocation.java:102)
    at org.jboss.ejb3.core.context.CurrentInvocationContextInterceptor.invoke(CurrentInvocationContextInterceptor.java:47)
    at org.jboss.aop.joinpoint.MethodInvocation.invokeNext(MethodInvocation.java:102)
    at org.jboss.aspects.currentinvocation.CurrentInvocationInterceptor.invoke(CurrentInvocationInterceptor.java:67)
    at org.jboss.aop.joinpoint.MethodInvocation.invokeNext(MethodInvocation.java:102)
    at org.jboss.ejb3.interceptor.EJB3TCCLInterceptor.invoke(EJB3TCCLInterceptor.java:86)
    at org.jboss.aop.joinpoint.MethodInvocation.invokeNext(MethodInvocation.java:102)
    at org.jboss.ejb3.stateless.StatelessContainer.dynamicInvoke(StatelessContainer.java:392)
    at org.jboss.ejb3.remoting.IsLocalInterceptor.invokeLocal(IsLocalInterceptor.java:88)
    at org.jboss.ejb3.remoting.IsLocalInterceptor.invoke(IsLocalInterceptor.java:75)
    at org.jboss.aop.joinpoint.MethodInvocation.invokeNext(MethodInvocation.java:102)
    at org.jboss.ejb3.async.impl.interceptor.AsynchronousClientInterceptor.invoke(AsynchronousClientInterceptor.java:143)
    at org.jboss.aop.joinpoint.MethodInvocation.invokeNext(MethodInvocation.java:102)
    at org.jboss.aspects.remoting.PojiProxy.invoke(PojiProxy.java:62)
    at $Proxy404.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.jboss.ejb3.proxy.impl.handler.session.SessionProxyInvocationHandlerBase.invoke(SessionProxyInvocationHandlerBase.java:185)
    at $Proxy407.canCreatePatVisit(Unknown Source)
    at com.atkosoft.cm.faces.patient.NewVisitForm.initFormWithMenuId(NewVisitForm.java:225)
    at com.atkosoft.cm.faces.patient.PatientSearchForm.goToDestination(PatientSearchForm.java:1302)
    ... 52 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.atkosoft.cm.patient.bizlogic.PatientControllerEJBBean.canCreatePatVisit(PatientControllerEJBBean.java:1856)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.jboss.aop.joinpoint.MethodInvocation.invokeTarget(MethodInvocation.java:122)
    at org.jboss.aop.joinpoint.MethodInvocation.invokeNext(MethodInvocation.java:111)
    at org.jboss.ejb3.interceptors.container.ContainerMethodInvocationWrapper.invokeNext(ContainerMethodInvocationWrapper.java:72)
    at org.jboss.ejb3.interceptors.aop.InterceptorSequencer.invoke(InterceptorSequencer.java:76)
    at org.jboss.ejb3.interceptors.aop.InterceptorSequencer.aroundInvoke(InterceptorSequencer.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor568.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.jboss.aop.advice.PerJoinpointAdvice.invoke(PerJoinpointAdvice.java:174)
    at org.jboss.aop.joinpoint.MethodInvocation.invokeNext(MethodInvocation.java:102)
    at org.jboss.ejb3.interceptors.aop.InvocationContextInterceptor.fillMethod(InvocationContextInterceptor.java:74)
    at org.jboss.aop.advice.org.jboss.ejb3.interceptors.aop.InvocationContextInterceptor_z_fillMethod_476205266.invoke(InvocationContextInterceptor_z_fillMethod_476205266.java)
    at org.jboss.aop.joinpoint.MethodInvocation.invokeNext(MethodInvocation.java:102)
    at org.jboss.ejb3.interceptors.aop.InvocationContextInterceptor.setup(InvocationContextInterceptor.java:90)
    at org.jboss.aop.advice.org.jboss.ejb3.interceptors.aop.InvocationContextInterceptor_z_setup_476205266.invoke(InvocationContextInterceptor_z_setup_476205266.java)
    at org.jboss.aop.joinpoint.MethodInvocation.invokeNext(MethodInvocation.java:102)
    at org.jboss.ejb3.async.impl.interceptor.AsynchronousServerInterceptor.invoke(AsynchronousServerInterceptor.java:128)
    at org.jboss.aop.joinpoint.MethodInvocation.invokeNext(MethodInvocation.java:102)
    at org.jboss.ejb3.connectionmanager.CachedConnectionInterceptor.invoke(CachedConnectionInterceptor.java:62)
    at org.jboss.aop.joinpoint.MethodInvocation.invokeNext(MethodInvocation.java:102)
    at org.jboss.ejb3.entity.TransactionScopedEntityManagerInterceptor.invoke(TransactionScopedEntityManagerInterceptor.java:56)
    at org.jboss.aop.joinpoint.MethodInvocation.invokeNext(MethodInvocation.java:102)
    at org.jboss.ejb3.AllowedOperationsInterceptor.invoke(AllowedOperationsInterceptor.java:47)
    at org.jboss.aop.joinpoint.MethodInvocation.invokeNext(MethodInvocation.java:102)
    at org.jboss.ejb3.tx.NullInterceptor.invoke(NullInterceptor.java:42)
    at org.jboss.aop.joinpoint.MethodInvocation.invokeNext(MethodInvocation.java:102)
    at org.jboss.ejb3.stateless.StatelessInstanceInterceptor.invoke(StatelessInstanceInterceptor.java:68)
    at org.jboss.aop.joinpoint.MethodInvocation.invokeNext(MethodInvocation.java:102)
    at org.jboss.ejb3.core.context.SessionInvocationContextAdapter.proceed(SessionInvocationContextAdapter.java:95)
    at org.jboss.ejb3.tx2.impl.CMTTxInterceptor.invokeInOurTx(CMTTxInterceptor.java:247)
    ... 84 more
```

Comment: How does BusinessHelper.getPatientServices obtain the bean instance?  Does it look it up from "java:"?

Comment: Thanks @bkail for the quick reply. It obtains it with a lookup from the context. PatientControllerEJB patContr = (PatientControllerEJB) ctx.lookup("PatientControllerEJBBean/remote");

Comment: Interesting.  I'm not a JBoss expert, so it's not really clear to me what's gone wrong, sorry.

Answer (score 1):

This might be JBoss related lookup issue.

Please use mappedName attribute with EJB Annotation. This should be your global JNDI name from your JBoss Container. JBoss recognizes mappedName as the global JNDI name of the EJB you are referencing. If you have specified a mappedName, then all other attributes are ignored and this global JNDI name is used for binding.

```
@EJB(mappedName="AdminControllerEJBBean/local")
private AdminControllerEJBLocal admContr;
```

Answer (score 0):

I think Dependency Injection can be done only for beans initiated by Container.